# Как использовать ASSERT_DEATH() в gtest?

Tags: c++, тестирование, gtest

При вызове функции strcpy строка из второго аргумента копируется в строку из первого аргумента. Если принимающая строка не инициализирована, вылетает ошибка сегментации.
Что нужно указать вторым аргументом ASSERT_DETH, чтоб отловить это

```
TEST(StrSopyTest, ReceiveBufferNotInitialized){
    char* src = "111";
    char* dest;
    ASSERT_DEATH(strcpy(dest, src), "");
}
```

Comment: ассоциация: [How to catch segmentation fault with Google Test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47583352/how-to-catch-segmentation-fault-with-google-test)

Comment: однако передача невалидных аргументов в функции вроде strcpy приводит к неопределенному поведению и протестировать их посредством gtest не выйдетю